# I want to override Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item

Tags: overrides, custom, methods

I want to override Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item  I have already made the extended file in my extension but I am not able to call it  please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a new module.
Make sure you have this in the `config.xml` of your module inside the `<global>` tag.

```
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <quote_item>Your_New_Class_Name_Here</quote_item>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
</models>
```

And make sure you have the declaration file for your module under `app/etc/modules`, named `[Namespace]_[Module].xml` with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namspace]_[Module]>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </[Namspace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear the cache when your are done.